# Cmake linker command fails to generate executable

Tags: c++, cmake, fortran, intel

I'm trying to compile a fortran binary which links with several libraries using `cmake`.

```
add_executable(myexe 
               ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/source/myexe.cpp 
               ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/API/F90/mod.f
               ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/API/F90/main.f)
set_property(TARGET myexe PROPERTY LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)
target_link_libraries(myexe mylib1 mylib2)
install(TARGETS myexe DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin)
```

`mylib1` and `mylib2` are targets in the same project and compile without an issue. However, the linker generates the following warning for `myexe`:

```
ifort: warning #10145: no action performed for file '/path/to/libmylib1.a'
ifort: warning #10145: no action performed for file '/path/to/libmylib2.a'
```

and `make install` fails with the error:

```
file INSTALL cannot find

      "/path/to/myexe"
```

I investigated `link.txt` to see the linker command and I find this:

```
/usr/local/bin/ifort   -c -lc++11 CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/__/source/myexe.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/API/F90/mod.f.o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/API/F90/main.f.o  -o myexe -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/lib/install/ ../LIB1/libmylib.a ../LIB2/libmylib2.a
```

What could I do to correct this linker command and resolve my error?

My cmake version is:

```
cmake version 3.14.1
```

Comment: Are `mylib1` and `mylib2` *targets* in your CMake project? Or are they static libraries (i.e. `libmylib1.a`)? If these libraries/targets don't exist your link step will fail and thus the executable will not be built.

Comment: They are targets

Comment: Can you post the full CMakeLists then? Are the targets created before you create the executable target?

Comment: I use `add_dependencies` to ensure that `myexe` depends on `mylib1` and `mylib2` and they are indeed compiled before `myexe`

Comment: So then you do call `add_library()` before `add_executable()`?

Comment: Yes, I do call both of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191402/discussion-between-developer-paul-and-newkid).